# LaTeX OS recognition

Tags: document-classes, ifplatform

Let's say I want to create a document class. Is there a way to make LaTex choose between packages (or package options) depending on the OS I'm working on?

More precisely, I want LaTeX to switch automatically between `\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}` on Linux derivatives and `\RequirePackage[latin1]{inputenc}` on Windows.

Comment: Package `ifplatform` should help

Comment: Why is your file in different encodings on the two platforms?

Comment: It is possible but a bad idea, the file encoding is independent of the operating system. windows is just as likely and capable of using utf8 as linux, and many older linux installations will default to latin1.  The class should _never_ default the encoding, which is a property of the _individual document_.

Answer (score 3):

Quick and dirty solution

The package `ifplatform` provides four `\if....` commands to check which system is underlying:

- `\ifwindows`
- `\iflinux`
- `\ifmacosx`
- `\ifcygwin`

Please note, that **shell-escape** must be enabled, otherwise all `\if...` macros by the package return *false*!

The basic question is, why one would use such a switch for encodings at all, as this is basically an editor setting, not an OS configuration issue.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifplatform}

% Possible, but not recommended!!!!!!!!
\iflinux
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\else
\ifwindows
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\fi
\fi


\begin{document}

\iflinux
\Huge Yes, this is the most beautiful system in the world
\else
\small Poor boy
\fi

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Guess which platform I use ;-)

Comment: (for varying definitions of "beautiful")

Comment: **don't do this** it means if you move the file from system to system, or use it over a shared drive from two different systems, it will be broken on one or other system.